# Can a CLR procedure open a port and listen on it?

Tags: sql-server, udpclient

I want to have a clr procedure that when called opens a udp port to listen for incoming data. It never returns to the caller. The caller has their timeout set to infinite. Will MSSQL server allow that?

Comment: Yeah, probably - but why?  Does Service Broker not meet your needs?

Comment: And on behalf of DBA's everywhere, please don't.  Have it run as a separate service that calls SQL Server.

Comment: @Mitch, I was afraid you were going to say that. :( and no service broker won't meet the need.

Comment: Yeah.  I figured you might.  Technically it is possible, and I can imagine cases where it would make sense (mostly in short lived transactions - exec table valued CLR UDF which connects to a IP and Port and streams the results back to the T-SQL Caller – maybe screen scraping from SQL Server Agent).  For something single-instance like reading from a syslog stream, though, I really recommend a separate service. T-SQL clients could then receive those results over Service Broker.

Comment: Therefore, the answer is yes, but for goodness sake please don't? Also, what would happen if that got clustered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a judgement call. I'd say the most determining factor is how long the socket remains open. If it is of a "transactional" length, which varies highly from system to system - then I would say this is fine. I don't see any issues with clustering since SQL Server does not have Active/Active clusters (but it would certainly be possible with NLB). The other determining factor would be whether the socket is single instance (listening on a non-broadcast port).

So, yes if:

- The function/stored procedure is to be called from T-SQL (SQL Server Agent or SSRS?)
- The function/stored procedure is expected to exit within a "transaction" time period
  (I'd say 30 seconds is typical - but on highly loaded system, a call which takes locks then waits for 30 seconds could be damning, so you will need to consider your use case.)
- The function is reentrant (can be run multiple times in parallel)

No if:

- The function is called from a C# or other more capable client (do your processing there - perhaps a library?)
- The function will wait an undetermined amount of time far in excess of the typical transaction length
- The function is single instance  (only a single session would be able to successfully execute the function)

Consider a few examples which illustrate the difference:

#### A SQL Server Agent job which populates a table daily with the rate chart scraped from a mainframe.

A CLR function is installed which takes an XML scraping document, connects to the Mainframe and uses TN 3270 Screen Scraping to return a result-set in the shape specified in the XML document

- Must be called from SQL (for ease of maintenance and failure reporting)
- Should timeout if it exceeds a set timeout (~30s)
- Can be run in multiple sessions in parallel
- **Answer:** A good candidate for an SQL CLR Function

#### A "Ticker" application where an application listens to UDP broadcasts of price updates and returns the result set to the client as a streamed result set

A CLR function opens a UDP broadcast listening port and asynchronously writes results back to the client.  This continues until an application defined end condition (specific packet payload, query cancellation, or timeout) is reached

- Must be called from SQL to handle a mix of platforms (some clients on PHP on Linux, others on VB6 on Windows)
- Has a defined and user controllable timeout (but partially fails this test since it would likely exceed the transaction duration).
- Can run in multiple sessions in parallel (broadcast)
- **Answer:** An "ok" candidate for SQL CLR Function

### A syslog server which dumps received events to a table

A function which opens a UDP listener on 0.0.0.0:514 and returns events as a streamed result set.

- No real reason it has to be called from SQL since it is buffering to a table regardless
- Has no timeout - expected to run 24/7
- Calling application (SQL Server Agent) has to ensure this function is always executing exactly once and restart it if it fails (reimplementation of service manager)
- **Answer:** Not a good fit for SQL CLR, consider Service Broker + an NT Service